# not able to execute commands in parallel in shell script through terminal

Tags: node.js, shell, npm, yaml

I am trying to execute below command in parallel using &

```
ENV=prod npm run SettingsSuite -- --runid Prod_E2E_$BUILD_NUMBER --APPNAME Prod_E2E --squad ops --track coreServices; echo $?  >> "$log_file" &
ENV=prod npm run InventorySuite -- --runid Prod_E2E_$BUILD_NUMBER --APPNAME Prod_E2E --squad ops --track coreServices; echo $?  >> "$log_file" & wait
```

but everytime it runs in sequential. my requirement is I need to run multiple commands in parallel and store exit code of each command in a log file.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: I've removed the `powershell` tag, because your code isn't PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a semicolon in there, only the echo commands are run in the background. You need to use some grouping parentheses:

```sh
(ENV=prod npm run SettingsSuite  -- --runid Prod_E2E_$BUILD_NUMBER --APPNAME Prod_E2E --squad ops --track coreServices; echo $?  >> "$log_file") &
(ENV=prod npm run InventorySuite -- --runid Prod_E2E_$BUILD_NUMBER --APPNAME Prod_E2E --squad ops --track coreServices; echo $?  >> "$log_file") & 
wait
```